# Open ball of the Discrete Metric

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, definition

Let $(X,d)$ be the discrete metric space, such that for $x,y\in X$,

$$d(x,y)=\cases{0 & $x=y$\\ 1 & $x\ne y$}$$

The open ball is defined as

$$B_r(x)=\cases{\{x\} & $0<\varepsilon \le 1$\\
X & $\varepsilon > 1$}$$

I am having trouble on understanding how we come to this definition of the open ball of the discrete metric. Any explanation would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Well... what are the open balls usually defined as? Also note that $r$ and $\varepsilon$ should be the same thing.

Comment: Use the definition $B_r(x)=\{p\in X\mid d(x,p)<r\}$

Comment: If ε is less (or equal)  than 1, then the only point that is ε-close to the point x, is in fact only the point x its self. If $ε>1&  then every element of X is ε-close to x

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, the open ball is *not* defined that way. The open ball $B_r(x)$ is the set $\{y\in X\mid d(x,y)<r\}$, for *any* metric space. But, if $d$ is the discrete metric, then:

- if $r\leqslant1$ then $d(x,y)<r\iff d(x,y)=0\iff y=x$, and therefore $B_r(x)=\{x\}$;
- if $r>1$, then, for each $y\in X$, $d(x,y)\leqslant1<r$, and therefore $B_r(x)=X$.

Comment: For the closed ball when $r > 1$: does this mean that since every subset of a discrete space is both open and closed, that the space itself is both open and closed since $B_r(x) = X$?

Comment: On *any* topological space, the whole space is both open and closed.

Comment: That makes sense. But what about when $X = \mathbb{N}$ and (for the closed ball) $B_{1}(x) = \mathbb{N}$? Does this mean that $\mathbb{N}$ is a closed and open set? I may be overthinking this.

Comment: When we are dealing with the discrete metric, *every* set is both closed and open. That's because, for any set $A$, $A=\bigcup_{a\in A}B_1(a)$, which implies that $A$ is open. And it is closed, since $X\setminus A$ is open.

Comment: So does that make the set $\mathbb{N}$ a closed an open set since it is equal to the closed and open ball when $r > 1$?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Great! Thank you for your time as always, José.